# Have UITableView separator appear below imageView

Tags: uitableview, swift

So I have a checklist type of thing going. However I decided to have the checkmarks appear on the left side of my cells. To accomplish this I am having each cell show a checkmark png image with `cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "check")`. This is working fine, however I am running into the problem where the separator line does not appear below the check mark as shown below. I don't like how this looks since the empty cell separators extend the whole length of the cell. Any suggestions to make the separator visible below the image?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add this method to the data source of your table view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.separatorInset = .zero
  }
```

or do the same thing in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

For Objective-C:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Comment: This worked. I edited it to be in swift though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can also change this in Storyboard:

When selecting the table view cell, change `Separator` to `Custom Insets` and fill in the desired insets.

[image]